# Adding a help button/parameter in SRSS Report

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have an SRSS report that I would like to display some HELP instructions as an option to click before running a report. Ideally I would like an image specified with the instructions to appear when the help option is chosen. I could do it with a help parameter but that would involve running the report. I am wondering if there is a way to include this as an option before running the report itself.

Comment: was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it can be tricky to implement if you have a lot of parameters involved. Here are some options based on the report type.

**If you have parameters:**

When you first navigate to a report, if all the parameters have a Default Value selected, it renders the report right away. You can add an Available Value called "Select One" that is selected by default. The help section built in to the report can be conditionally hidden or shown based on if that value is selected.

So when you go to the report, it will show "Select One" and the help section. Once you select an actual parameter value, it will switch to show the body of the report instead.

**If you have no parameters:**

Start with a report that has the help section and a button to continue to the main report. This button can be a Report or URL link to navigate to the main report. Or you can use a subreport to embed them together based on your design preferences.

Comment: Great I will give this a shot!

Comment: I am having trouble getting the report to render automatically when setting all to default values. Just to make sure I am understanding correctly the "Select one" value is a parameter value created by the user to be passed rather than an SRSS built in feature correct?

Comment: Nevermind  I got it now! I was putting " " for the default values as oppose to leaving the field empty